# Php 5.3.18 синтаксис ООП

Tags: ооп, php

Здравствуйте! Только начинаю разбираться с ООП в php, подскажите, пожалуйста, какой должен быть синтаксис определения переменных в классе и обращения к ним, почему-то вот на такой код php (5.3.18) ругается:

```
class item {
   $xls_code=0;
   $name="";
   function __construct($xls_code_param, $name_param) {
   this->xls_code=1;
   this->name="---------";
     echo "<br>Объект создан";
   }

}
```

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting T_FUNCTION on line 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class item {
   $xls_code=0;
   $name="";
   function __construct($xls_code_param, $name_param) {
   this->xls_code=1;
   this->name="---------";
     echo "<br>Объект создан";
   }

}
```

вот так хотя бы

```
class item {
   public $xls_code_param=0;
   public $name="";
   function __construct($xls_code, $name_param) {
   $this->xls_code=1;
   $this->name="---------";
   echo "<br>Объект создан";
   }

}

$a = new item(1,2);
```

Comment: Спасибо, большое. Работает. Почему-то я думала, что public можно пропускать (

Comment: Обязательно нужно указывать scope переменной в классе: public, protected, private

Comment: Ну это php 5.* там много всякого.

Comment: да, спасибо, уже поняла